# Azure Eventhub Apache Storm issue

Tags: azure, apache-storm, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I followed [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-event-hubs-java-storm-getstarted/) article to try eventhub with Apache Storm, But when I run the Storm topology it was receiving events for a minute and then it stopped receiving. So I've restarted my program and then it was receiving the remaining messages. Every time I run the program after a minute it couldn't receive from eventhub. Please help me with the possibilities of the issue...

Should I change any configurations at Storm or Zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

The above jar contains a fix for a known issue in the QPID JMS client, which is used by the Event Hub spout implementation. When the service sends an empty frame (heartbeat to keep connection alive), a decoding error occurs in the client and that causes the client to stop processing commands. Details of this issue can be found here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-6378